# Shortcut to bring mouse focused window to front

Tags: awesome-wm

Is there some way to bring the focused window to the front in awesome without clicking with the mouse?

I'm looking e.g. to find Mod-F1 to "bring window to front" and Mod-F2 to "send window to bottom". Expecting it to take the window that mouse is hovering to front or back.

Comment: We don't do software recomendations but [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) would statisfy your need.

Answer (score 0):

Add these bindings to your rc.lua file; assuming you are using a slightly modified default 3.5 config file, these should fit in the `clientkeys` definition.

```
awful.key({ modkey, }, "F1", function (c) c:raise() end),
awful.key({ modkey, }, "F2", function (c) c:lower() end),
```